# rxplot for vector like types

Tags: ros, rxplot

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

trying to plot some fields from a vector-like ROS message, I can't find the right syntax to do so. I have a ROSmsg 'DataMsg' which contains:

`uint32 length
float64[] data`

And a message on top of that DataMsgs, which has:

`DataMsg[] data`

How do I plot the data inside e.g. DataMsgs/data[0]/data[0] with rxplot?
I tried various lines, but noone of them worked so far...

regards,

Steven

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9175/rxplot-for-vector-like-types/) by [Steven Bellens](https://answers.ros.org/users/55/steven-bellens/) on ROS Answers with karma: 735 on 2011-02-23

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You're right to use [#] notation with slashes

For example this works:

```
rxplot /wide_stereo/right/camera_info/D[2]
```

And thsi works:

```
rxplot /tf/transforms[0]/transform/translation/x
```

I'm not finding a vector of vectors at the moment on our system but it should work too.  If you find it doesn't support that file a ticket.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2011-02-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 5